# Apple Music API - Create a Playlist

Tags: objective-c, mpmediaquery, itunes-sdk, apple-music, mpmedialibrary

I have been exploring the Apple Music API to see what kind of functionality I can expect to be able to use in an iOS app. I have created a little test app that gains permission from the user and outputs the playlists I have (and songs) to `NSLog`.

```
MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
            [myPlaylistsQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingPlaylist];
            NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];
            
            for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
                NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
                
                NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
                
                for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
                    NSString *songTitle =
                    [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
                    NSLog (@"\t\t%@", songTitle);
                }
            }
```

From this, I have been able to deduce the following (but I'm not 100% certain):

- the playlist (basic info: name, id) is stored locally on the device
- the playlist songs are also pulled from local storage *but* if the playlist hasn't been downloaded to the device it goes off to Apple to grab the song list.

So far, so good. What I want to know is:

- is there a way of creating a playlist from my app (via the API)?

I know there is an `MPMediaPlaylist` `addItem` and `add` method but can't seem to find a way of creating the new playlist itself.

According to this page it should be possible: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/blog/apple-music-api-faq/

> **Can a developer create brand new playlists on the user’s device with the Apple Music API?**
>
> Yes. The API allows develops to new create playlists on the user’s device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured this out. If you use the following code you can generate a new playlist and perform an action on it.

```
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID]; //uuid for the playlist
[[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] getPlaylistWithUUID:uuid creationMetadata:[[MPMediaPlaylistCreationMetadata alloc] initWithName:@"YOUR PLAYLIST NAME"] completionHandler:^(MPMediaPlaylist * _Nullable playlist, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"All ok let's do some stuff with the playlist!"); 
    }
}];
```

Apple's documentation on the whole API is severely lacking in terms of sample code and practical examples!

Comment: Hi, I know it is almost 2 years later but still there are no objective-c (one swift one but I am too old to learn a new language :) sample apps  to access Apple Music.  You would be my hero if you could share yours with me somehow.

Comment: If that is not possible can you help out here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853478/error-using-skcloudservicecontroller-api-to-check-apple-music-capabilities